# How to move an enumerate environment to the right?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate

How can I horizontally align `\begin{enumerate}` more to the right? At the moment I'm using the code below:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item sometext
\item sometext
\item sometext
\end{enumerate}
```

But it goes too left in my document. I would like to add some horizontal space to the left, so that the list would be more center on the page...any advices? =) Thank you for any help!

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28618/enumerated-list-indentation help at all?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `enumitem` package is a good one to load for all kinds of customisation of list environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=3cm]
\item sometext
\item sometext
\item sometext
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1cm]
\item sometext
\item sometext
\item sometext
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also set the `leftmargin` value for all `enumerate` environments within the current scope by using `\setlist`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=3cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item sometext
\item sometext
\item sometext
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item some other text
\item some other text
\item some other text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Something like this, you mean?

```
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=2cm,rightmargin=2cm]
```

Also, see [Enumerated list indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28618/enumerated-list-indentation)

Comment: Your answer is not complete unless you state the necessary packages

Comment: @MERose It's obviously a modification of OP's MWE. That said, nobody else seems to have minded (or noticed) for the past 8 years, so I think I'll let this one slide.